# Why have I lost 7 reputation from one downvote?

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation dropdown indicates that I've had a change in reputation of -7 from this [question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/81/who-does-mollie-represent-in-animal-farm), which only has one downvote. Therefore, shouldn't I have only lost 2 reputation instead of 7?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [detailed reputation breakdown](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/123/fi12?tab=reputation) (available from expanding the list item by clicking on the little arrow) shows that you both got a downvote (-2) and someone revoking his earlier upvote (-5).

[image]

Comment: Both great answers nonetheless :)

Comment: Hey, I'm curious; what happens if I upvote something, un-upvote it, and then re-upvote it again, in quick succession? Not that anyone would particularly want to do that, but on mobile I've done that accidentally a couple times, due to either fat-fingering, or lag causing my vote to not register right away (so I try again), How does that affect the rep of the "victim"?

Comment: @kristan I *guess* (albeit not know) it needs to cross the 5-minute grace period (after which the post needs to be edited before you can change your vote) to register as a recorded upvote/unupvote event. However, I don't know if a following upvote cancels the whole record entirely.

Answer (score 8):

You got an **unupvote** (-5) as well as a downvote (-2): presumably from the same person, changing their upvote to a downvote. From your [reputation history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/123/fi12?tab=reputation) (don't click if you [want to preserve that number in the top of your reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/255996/278659)):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ah, that's much clearer. Thanks for the quick answer!